# Render multiple JSON results to HTML list in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dom, rendering

I'm trying to render a list of JSON objects in react (result). I have most of the functionality working, however I'm only able to show one HTML JSON object out of a list that has multiple entries. (Example: I search for SMITH and I get multiple entries in the console however only one entry gets returned in HTML) [Here's a screenshot of the list that is rendered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1SkH.png)

What's the best method to render a list of all my JSON entries rather than a single entry?

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import login from '../pages/login.js';
import store from '../libs/store.js';
var jsforce = require('jsforce');

class menuScreen extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const data = store.getState();

    this.state = {

        username: '',
        messages: data.messages
    }
}

handleSearch(e) {
    this.setState({username: e.target.value})
}

handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({
        username: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100)
    });

}

onLinkClicked() {

    var parent = this.state.username
    //console.log(this.state.username)
    var conn = new jsforce.Connection({serverUrl: 'https://cs63.salesforce.com', accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem('token')})
    conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE LastName='" + parent + "'", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }

        var a = result

        a.records.forEach((item) => {
            result = (item.Name + ' ' + item.Phone);
            this.setState({result: result});

        });

    })
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.result)
    return (

        <div className='menubox' id='menubox'>
            <div className='searchbar-container'>
                <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                    <input type='text' size='25' placeholder='Contact Last Name' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.username}/>
                    <button type='submit' onClick={this.onLinkClicked.bind(this)}>
                        Search
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: this.state.result } }></div>
        </div>

    )

 }

}

export default menuScreen;
```

Comment: JSON is not an object, it's a string.

Comment: you should stop what you are doing and remove the ability to run SQL code in your browser. never run sql queries via JS in the browser. anyone can pause on a breakpoint and write their own SQL query to execute.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I'm testing locally at the moment. I plan to put an escape in my query once I have everything working.

Comment: im not talking about escaping queries. im talking about running them in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STOP! do not give the browser access to your database. Do not let the browser run sql queries.

```
conn.query("SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE LastName='" + parent + "'", (err, result) => {
```

if I set a breakpoint on this line and decide to run my own query it wouldn't be good.

```
conn.query("DROP table Contact")
```

Now, with that said... your issue is you are only ever storing one result to be viewed

```
const elems = [];
a.records.forEach((item) => {
    result = (item.Name + ' ' + item.Phone);
    elems.push(result);
});
this.setState({result: elems});
```